# NSTableView: get notified when floating subview gets removed

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, floating, nsscrollview

I have a custom `NSTableView` with floating group rows. These rows behave differently withing `drawRect`, according to whenever they are actually floating, or not. (There is only 1 floating row in an `NSTableView` at a time, that's the table's default behaviur)

I can track when they start floating, with a custom `NSScrollView` subclass, with obseverable override for the `addFloatingSubview:forAxis:` method.

I can't track when they stop floating though.

The [NSScrollView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScrollView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSScrollView/addFloatingSubview:forAxis:) tells me:

> You are responsible for keeping track of the floating views and removing them via `removeFromSuperview` when they should no longer float.

But it seems `NSTableView` does not call `removeFromSuperview` neither on (my custom subclass of) `NSTableRowView`; nor on the `NSView` used as a "cell" for the group row.

How to get notified when the `NSTableView` stops floating a subview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it: [NSTableRowView.floating](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableRowView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSTableRowView/floating)

`NSTableView` has so many subcomponents, I just did not seek for this on the right/trivial place :)